# How to update the labels in app as soon as JSON is fetched from server? If should be real time update

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am making a cricket app. I want to update the labels in iOS from URL every time server sends me the JDON file. How should I write the URL code?

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

struct jsonScore : Decodable  {
    let comment : String
    let venuDetails : String
    let valueToDisplay : String
    let bowlingTeam : String
    let battingTeam : String

    let overs : Double
    let targetScore : Int
    let wickets : Int
    let score : Int

    let striker : striker
    let nonStriker : nonStriker
    let strikerBowler : strikerBowler
}

struct striker : Decodable{
    let name: String
    let runs: String
    let balls: String
    let fours: String
    let sixes: String
}

struct nonStriker : Decodable{
    let name: String
    let runs: String
    let balls: String
    let fours: String
    let sixes: String
}

struct strikerBowler : Decodable{
    let name : String
    let overs : String
    let maidens : String
    var runs : String
    let wickets : String
}

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var Comment: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var VenuDetails: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var ValueToDisplay: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var battingTeam: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bowlingTeam: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var wickets: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var overs: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var score: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var striker: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var strikerRun: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var nonStriker: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var nonStrikerRun: UILabel!

    @IBOutlet weak var strikerBowlerName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var strikerBowlerOver: UILabel!

    var timer = Timer()
    // start the timer

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(getUpdatedData), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    }

    @objc func getUpdatedData() {
        let jsonUrlString = "url from server"

        guard let url = URL(string : jsonUrlString ) else
        { return }

        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, err) in
            guard let data = data else { return }
            //get your updated data here and update it into the UI.

            do {
                let jsonscore = try JSONDecoder().decode(jsonScore.self, from: data)

                self.VenuDetails.text = jsonscore.venuDetails
                self.Comment.text = jsonscore.comment
                self.bowlingTeam.text = jsonscore.bowlingTeam
                self.battingTeam.text = jsonscore.battingTeam
                self.ValueToDisplay.text = jsonscore.valueToDisplay
                self.wickets.text = String(jsonscore.wickets)
                self.overs.text = String(jsonscore.overs)

                self.score.text = String(jsonscore.score)
                self.striker.text = jsonscore.striker.name + "*"
                self.strikerRun.text = jsonscore.striker.runs

                self.nonStriker.text = jsonscore.nonStriker.name
                self.nonStrikerRun.text = jsonscore.nonStriker.runs

                self.strikerBowlerName.text = jsonscore.strikerBowler.name
                self.strikerBowlerOver.text = jsonscore.strikerBowler.overs

                print(jsonscore)

            }catch let jsonErr{
                print("Error serializing json:", jsonErr)
            }
        }.resume()
    }
}
```

How to I write the code so that as soon as JSON is fetched from server it gets updated in the app? I used timer also but the labels in app are not updating after first update. I want to update the app label as soon as server sends the JSON file and the update should be repeatedly.

Please help me writing the code.

Comment: It is a really bad idea to try to download data from a remote server twice per second.

Comment: You may want to take a look at sockets.

Comment: does this code of yours work or not? if not, then try updating the labels in main queue.

Answer (score 0):

As @Rmaddy said your timer use is quiet a bad idea. You can see why in the apple's [Energy Efficiency Guide for iOS Apps](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/EnergyGuide-iOS/MinimizeTimerUse.html)

> Timers prevent the CPU from going to or staying in the idle state,
>   which increases energy usage and consumes battery power.

That kind of over use will end up draining the device battery.

You should use something more efficient like [web sockets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket)(As @the4kman suggested). By using web sockets you will need to change a little bit your approach. You should consider to change your server to notify the app instead of the app being constantly downloading data from the server.

Here are some web sockets libraries that you can use:

[Starscream](https://github.com/daltoniam/Starscream)

[Socket.io](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift)

[SwiftWebSocket](https://github.com/tidwall/SwiftWebSocket)